# Does Ansible duplicate role variables for role dependencies that enable "allow_duplicates"?

Tags: ansible

Does Ansible duplicate role variables for [role dependencies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies) that have enabled `allow_duplicates`?

For example, given a playbook that includes more than once role `application-environment` that allows duplicates, will Ansible create multiple copies of its variables?

*meta/main.yml*:

```
---
allow_duplicates: yes
dependencies:
  - src: git+http://javasource/git/ansible/roles/organization
    version: 1.1.0
```

*vars/main.yml*:

```
---
application_directory: "{{ organization.directory }}/{{ application_name }}"
application_component_directory: "{{ application_directory }}/{{ application_component_name }}"
```

If Ansible *does not* create multiple copies of these variables, how could I rework the role so that it can support multiple variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find some helpful information [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

About `vars`:

> Anything in the vars directory of the role overrides previous versions of that variable in namespace.

About `defaults`:

> Tasks in each role will see their own role’s defaults. Tasks defined outside of a role will see the last role’s defaults.

Comment: I think my problem was due to role variable scoping and overrides.  I had expected certain variables to have specific values at higher level scopes, but hadn't set those variables at the scope, so the variables still had values assigned by roles applied earlier.